# Validation failed for one or more entities when trying to commit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, viewmodel

I am having an issue in my helpdesk software that I am creating.  When a user tries to edit a knowledgebase, and save it on the commit method in my repository base they are getting this error:

[image]

Here is the model controller code where I match the model fields up with the view model fields then I commit the changes:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditTechKnowledgebase(EditKnowledgebase editknowledgebase)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Knowledgebase knowledgebase = new Knowledgebase();
                knowledgebase.Category = editknowledgebase.Category;
                knowledgebase.CategoryId = editknowledgebase.CategoryId;
                knowledgebase.CreatedBy = editknowledgebase.CreatedBy;
                knowledgebase.CreatedById = editknowledgebase.CreatedById;
                //knowledgebase.CreatedDate = editknowledgebase.CreatedDate;
                knowledgebase.Description = editknowledgebase.Description;
                knowledgebase.Note = knowledgebase.Note;

                knowledgebases.Update(knowledgebase);
                knowledgebases.Commit();

                return RedirectToAction("TechKnowledgebaseList", new { createdById = editknowledgebase.CreatedById, categoryId = editknowledgebase.CategoryId, typeId = editknowledgebase.TypeId });
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories.Where(c => c.Status == 1), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
                ViewBag.TypeId = new SelectList(db.Roles, "RoleId", "RoleDescription");

                return View(editknowledgebase);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's the schema in the database? Usually that error indicates some aspect of the schema has been violated (eg. not giving a value to a non-nullable column).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by a mismatch between what you are saving and the database schema. It could be attempting to save a null in a non-null field for instance, or a double being saved to an int field, or a date less than  1900-01-01 being saved in a datetime field.

You can catch DBValidationExceptions like so:

```
try
{
    knowledgebases.Update(knowledgebase);
    knowledgebases.Commit();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    foreach (var validationErrors in ex.EntityValidationErrors)
    {
        foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

this will write out every property that is causing the error.

Make non-null fields mandatory by decorating viewmodel properties with the `Required` attribute, then this would  fail the `ModelState.IsValid` test and be handled. For non-null fields the user doesn't have access to, make sure they have a default value.

Comment: User thank you but then what do I do just return the view?

Comment: @djblois tbh, would be better to make non-null fields mandatory by decorating model properties with the `Required` attribute, then this would  fail the `ModelState.IsValid` test. For non-null fields the user doesn't have access to, make sure they have a default value.

Comment: User sorry I was out of town.  Back today, will look at it now.